How to pass an image sequence for a canvas in React?
I have a list of 150 images called 0001.jpg, 0002.jpg ... 0150.jpg.
This is what I'm doing so far (only included the relevant code):
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function getCurrentFrame(index) {
  return `../${index.toString().padStart(4, "0")}.jpg`;
}

const ImageCanvas = ({ scrollHeight, numFrames, width, height }) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [frameIndex, setFrameIndex] = useState(0);

  // Step 1: Load images
  function preloadImages() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= numFrames; i++) {
      const img = new Image();
      const imgSrc = getCurrentFrame(i);
      img.src = imgSrc;
      setImages((prevImages) => [...prevImages, img]);
    }
  }

    const render = () => {
      console.log(images[frameIndex]);
      context.drawImage(images[frameIndex], 0, 0);
      requestId = requestAnimationFrame(render);
    };

    render();

I get this error when it tries to drawImage:

"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.
at render"

console.log(images[frameIndex]); prints the correct element three to five times before showing the error:
<img src="../0001.jpg"> 

I'm certain the image source is correct because I set "img.src" in preloadImages() to the same src "../0001.jpg" and it shows the image.
Any idea what could be going wrong? Is there a better way to do it?

I was able to solve the error above by moving my photos into the public folder. However, now only the first image (0001.jpg) appears.

Feel free to [edit] the question to show your current situation. You are running a dev server to host the images? Check the URLs to make sure they're all 200.

It's critical to know when your images are loaded with the 'onload' callback. Check my answer below

Hard to say without the code on how you grab the context etc...
I use to work a lot with Canvas. Here I would load in memory all the images beforehand and do something like this recursive animation loop:


const framesUrls = ["https://iili.io/dxVWkZB.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVW8CP.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhjzQ.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhNLB.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVheqP.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhk11.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhvrF.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhSdg.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhU7a.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhgkJ.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhrmv.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVh6IR.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhPXp.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhiLN.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhLBI.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhQ1t.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhZrX.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhD2n.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhb7s.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhmkG.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhppf.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVj9I4.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjHhl.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjJQ2.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVj2BS.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVj3E7.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjF49.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjf2e.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjqYu.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjBkb.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjCpj.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjoTx.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjxhQ.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjzQV.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjTCB.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjuEP.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjA41.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVj53F.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVj7Yg.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjYva.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjayJ.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVjlTv.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVj0jR.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXTwQ.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXutV.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXRoB.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVX5MP.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVX7P1.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXaKF.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXccg.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXlSa.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVX1HJ.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXEAv.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXGNR.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXMtp.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXWoN.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXXVI.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXhPt.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXwKX.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXNln.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXOSs.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXkHG.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXvRf.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVX8N4.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXSDl.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXgx2.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXrVS.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVX4i7.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXPf9.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXile.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXsUu.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXQHb.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXZRj.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXtOx.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXDDQ.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXmxV.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXpWB.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXyiP.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhHf1.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhJ0F.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhdUg.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVh3Ja.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhF5J.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhKOv.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhfbR.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhCWN.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhnsI.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhxft.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhz0X.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhIgn.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhuJs.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhA5G.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhRef.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVh5b4.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhYzl.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhaX2.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhcsS.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVh0q7.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVh119.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhEge.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhMdu.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhV5b.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhWej.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVhXmx.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWSG1.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWr3g.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVW4aa.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVW68J.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWPyv.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWsuR.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWLjp.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWQZN.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWtnI.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWDGt.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWb6X.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWpFn.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWyas.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVX98G.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXJ9f.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXdu4.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVX2wl.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVX3t2.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXKnS.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXfM7.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXqP9.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXCFe.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXncu.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXo8b.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXz9j.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVXIAx.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWMG9.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWGC7.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVW0j2.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVW1QS.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWV4e.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWX3u.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWhYb.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWjvj.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWwyx.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWOTQ.jpg","https://iili.io/dxVWejV.jpg"];


// Errored images

const erroredImages = [];

// Create array of Image elements
const images = framesUrls.map(frameUrl => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = frameUrl;
  img.onload = () => {
    console.log("Successfully loaded frame url: ", frameUrl);
    registerLoadingProgress();
  }
  img.onerror = () => {
    erroredImages.push(img);
    console.error("Failed to load frame url: ", frameUrl);
    registerLoadingProgress();
  };
  return img;
});

let loadedCount = 0;

function registerLoadingProgress() {
  loadedCount++;
  if (loadedCount === framesUrls.length) {
    console.clear();
    console.log("Loading complete - Start animation loop");
    drawImages();
  }
}

const frameRate = 30; // 30 frames per second
const ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

function drawImages(frameNumber = 0, lastFrame = Date.now()) {
  if (images[frameNumber]) {
    if (!erroredImages.includes(images[frameNumber])) {
      ctx.drawImage(images[frameNumber], 0, 0, 320, 180);
    }
    if (Date.now() - lastFrame >= 1000 / frameRate) {
      frameNumber++;
      lastFrame = Date.now();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(() => drawImages(frameNumber, lastFrame));
  }
}
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="180"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>



